# Google Maps API(V3) で、Places ライブラリの AutoComplete のみ使用する方法はありますか？

Tags: api, google-maps

Google Maps API(v3) で、AutoComplete を使いたいため [Placesライブラリ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=ja)を有効にしているのですが、  
地図上のマーカー以外にも関係のない場所もクリックできてしまいます。  
AutoCompleteのみ使用する方法か、またはマーカー以外の場所をクリックさせない方法はありますでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

ランドマークのラベルを非表示にすることで可能かと思います。

```js
function initialize() {
  // create map 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 35.683373,
      lng: 139.769212
    },
    zoom: 18
  });
  // define map type
  map.mapTypes.set('nopoi', new google.maps.StyledMapType([{
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
      visibility: "off"
    }]
  }], 　 {
    name: "NO POI"
  }));
  // apply maptype
  map.setMapTypeId('nopoi');

  // test: search restaurant around marunouchi
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.search({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(35.683373, 139.769212),
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  }, function(results, status) {
    for (var _r = 0; _r < results.length; ++_r) {
      // create marker
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[_r].geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: results[_r].name
      });
    }
  });
};
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

```
// create map 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
        lat: 35.683373,
        lng: 139.769212
    },
    zoom: 18
});
// define map type
map.mapTypes.set('nopoi', new google.maps.StyledMapType([{ 
    featureType: "poi", 
    elementType: "labels", 
    stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
    }] 
}],　{
    name: "NO POI"
}));
// apply maptype
map.setMapTypeId('nopoi');
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。  
なるほど非表示にする方法は思いつきませんでした。  
  
しかしマーカー以外のクリッカブルな場所をなくすとなると、ほとんどのラベルを消す必要があるみたいです・・・。  
ランドマークが消えてしまい地図としての使い勝手が下がるため、他に方法がなければ採用したいと思います。